# MVVM, WPF changing view after double click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I have Grid with tableView with data from excel file. I want to assign a model from another grid (selected in another tableview) after double clicking.
My code works but the user sees the change only after some changes on the tableview (eg sort by column).

Somy view

```
<Grid PreviewKeyDown="Grid_PreviewKeyDown2">
                        <dxg:GridControl x:Name="grid"  
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew"  
                                        EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True"
                                        SelectionMode="Row"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding ListaZExcela, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding ZaznaczonyDokument}">
                            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                                <dxg:TableView x:Name="view" 
                                               ShowFixedTotalSummary="True"
                                               AllowGrouping="False" 
                                               AllowEditing="False"
                                               ShowGroupPanel="False">

                                    <dxg:TableView.InputBindings>
                                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                                                      Command="{Binding DoubleClickCommand}">
                                            <!--<MouseBinding.CommandParameter>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Convert}">
                                                    <Binding ElementName="grid" Path="SelectedItem"/>
                                                    <Binding ElementName="gridKontrah" Path="SelectedItem"/>
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </MouseBinding.CommandParameter>-->
                                        </MouseBinding>
                                    </dxg:TableView.InputBindings>
                                </dxg:TableView>
                            </dxg:GridControl.View>

                        </dxg:GridControl>
                    </Grid>
```

my viewmodel

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ObservableCollection<DokumentModel> _listaZExcela;
        public ObservableCollection<DokumentModel> _listaZExcelaPom;
        public ObservableCollection<KontrahentModel> _listaKontrahent;
        private BackgroundWorker _worker;
        private BackgroundWorker _worker2;
        private int _progressPercentage = 0;
        private bool _startEnabled = true;
        private bool _cancelEnabled = false;
        public KontrahentModel _zaznaczonyKontrahent;
        public DokumentModel _zaznaczonyDokument;

        public string _filePath;


        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Opencmd = new DelegateCommand(OpenCmd);
            //DoubleClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(DoubleClickCmd);
            importujCommand = new DelegateCommand(StartProcess2);
            DoubleClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteMy);
            _listaZExcela = new ObservableCollection<DokumentModel>();
            _listaZExcelaPom = new ObservableCollection<DokumentModel>();
            _listaKontrahent = new ObservableCollection<KontrahentModel>();
            DajKontrahentow();
            _zaznaczonyKontrahent = new KontrahentModel();
            _zaznaczonyDokument = new DokumentModel();

        }





        public ICommand DoubleClickCommand { get; set; }



        public void ExecuteMy()
        {

            ZaznaczonyDokument.Kontrahent = ZaznaczonyKontrahent;
            ZaznaczonyDokument.KontrahentNazwaskr = ZaznaczonyKontrahent.NazwaSkr;

        }



        #endregion

        #region OnPropertyChangedRegion
        public KontrahentModel ZaznaczonyKontrahent
        {
            get
            {
                return _zaznaczonyKontrahent;
            }
            set
            {
                _zaznaczonyKontrahent = value;
                OnParameterChanged("ZaznaczonyKontrahent");
            }
        }

        public DokumentModel ZaznaczonyDokument
        {
            get
            {
                return _zaznaczonyDokument;
            }
            set
            {
                _zaznaczonyDokument = value;
                OnParameterChanged("ZaznaczonyDokument");
            }
        }





        public ObservableCollection<DokumentModel> ListaZExcela
        {
            get
            {
                return _listaZExcela;
            }
            set
            {
                _listaZExcela = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ListaZExcela");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(params string[] nazwy)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                foreach (string nazwaWlasnosci in nazwy)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new
                    PropertyChangedEventArgs(nazwaWlasnosci));
            }
        }
        #endregion



    }
```

}

Data assignment is in ExecuteMy.  I did not paste some of the code to make it more clean

Comment: So it's the `tableView` that is not updated then? Also does `ZaznaczonyDokument` implements `INPC`?

Comment: Please can you post the code from DoubleClickCommand ?